# How do we upsert data to Salesforce in IOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, salesforce

I am using the Salesforce CRM in one of my IOS - iPad project, we are trying to add data back to Salesforce. Can anybody tell me how this can be achieved?

We are using the SOAP API and also SudzC.com library. Below is the sample Request snippet.
How do we generate externalIDFieldName?

```
<soapenv:Body>
     <urn:upsert>
        <!--Custom Field defined in Setup as the External ID-->
       <urn:externalIDFieldName>
               <b>External_Id__c</b>
           </urn:externalIDFieldName>
       <urn:sObjects xsi:type="Account"> <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <b><!--Existing Id, this record will be updated--></b>
               <External_Id__c><b>ars1</b></External_Id__c>
               <Name><b>Acme Rocket Superstore</b></Name>
               <b><!--You may enter ANY elements at this point--></b>
               <NumberOfEmployees><b>340</b></NumberOfEmployees>
        </urn:sObjects>
       <urn:sObjects xsi:type="Account">
               <b><!--New External Id, this record will be created (ensure required fields are present)--></b>
               <External_Id__c><b>ams1</b></External_Id__c>
               <Name><b>Acme Medical Supplies</b></Name>
               <NumberOfEmployees><b>17</b></NumberOfEmployees>
        </urn:sObjects>
     </urn:upsert>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the field name: `External_Id__c` you can tell that this is a custom field (ends in `__c`) on the Account object which is specific to the Salesforce org you're interacting with. Presumably it's supposed to represent an ID from an external system, but I can't tell you if someone is creating a field for you to use in the app, or if it's supposed to be an ID from another database somewhere.

You need to talk to the engineers working on the Salesforce side to find out what it's purpose is, if it is for you then I'd suggest some combination of the current date, time and another piece of information to generate something unique.

Comment: Thanks LaceySnr... I was able to crack it... but now i am getting error: "Must send a concrete entity type", any idea regrading this?

Answer (score 0):

upsert is update/insert command. based on the data(try passing pass the table name and id) u send, it will either update or insert record in cloud.